# Google Search Console says "Page isn't usable on Mobile" but screenshot rendered by Googlebot smartphone is inaccurate

Tags: google-search-console

Our website got a "Page isn't usable on mobile" error on Google Search Console but the screenshot rendered by Googlebot smartphone is totally inaccurate from the actual mobile view. It said "Clickable elements too close together," and "Content wider than screen"

This is taken by Googlebot: https://prnt.sc/8hrffemsqqaW
But these are the actual mobile views: https://prnt.sc/-lnaoWh34FQZ, https://prnt.sc/tkOBAEKuoVlj

How can we possibly take some actions if what Google is seeing is inaccurate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ^ not sure how more I can clarify. I'd like to know how we can possibly take some actions in order to fix these errors: "Clickable elements too close together," and "Content wider than screen," when the screenshot taken by Googlebot smartphone is different from the actual mobile view.

Comment: Are you looking at the screenshot from the GSC URL inspection or the Mobile-friendly test? The latter tends to have rendering problems as it has to reload resources every time and has a limited timeout. Either way, check the more info tab to see if any errors would cause it to display badly.

Answer (score 0):

you may use this code to setup font-size on css.

```
<style>
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

You may choose font-size from 20 px and higher

Learn more on gsa indexing     [Click Here](https://amzn.to/43IAh3o)